# htaccess - rewrite URL to include CSS and JS

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.(css|js|htc|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This .htaccess redirects everything to `index.php?path=SOMETHING` where I can pick it up (SOMETHING path) and show appropriate content (views).

The problem is with including `.css/.js` files.

If I use `www.website.com/something` everything works (css path is like `/css/style.css` and it's searching in the `www.website.com/css/style.css`). But if I use `www.website.com/something/2` everything crashes because it's searching in `www.website.com/something/css/style.css` folder.

How to set root (?) everytime to `www.website.com` (whatever path is)? So I **should still have acccess to my 'path' variable** but everything should point to the website root and not `/some/...` path when including my files.

Comment: Can you try to clarify a bit more about how you include your css and js documents? Also, if the css is one file, independent to the given url, then why make it dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem is in the way how you write links to css/js/image files.**

Instead of including css/js/images using relative URLs to the current page:

```
href="css/style.css"
```

you should use URLs relative to the root (**notice the leading slash**):

```
href="/css/style.css"
```

or use absolute URLs (that will include domain name -- much less preferred approach).

This is a typical mistake when designing website (html part) when site uses Nice URLs/URL Rewritting. This is -- it's now that rewrite engine breaks URLs -- it's browser that sends them like that (`/something/css/style.css`) in first place.